# My USB drive isn't working for Computers after I checked if it could be configured to xbox 360

Tags: xbox360, usb

I checked to see if I could configure my USB drive for the Xbox so that it could hold Cbox files. But after I saw that it would delete all files, I cancelled.

But now my USB drive won't work on any computers. It always comes up with "Please insert a disk into removable disk (F:)."

I have tried changing it back to PC format by going to "Computer" -> File, clicking the icon of the drive and then going to "Format..". But it also comes up with "Insert disk".

Comment: Looks like an unrecognized filesystem. Doesn't the XBOX have a format option? Perhaps you could use a GParted live CD to format it back to FAT or NTFS or whatever filesystem you had before.

Comment: What do you see when you open Disk Management?

Comment: Are you sure it's F:?  Does the thumbdrive have any auto-run software on it, e.g. SanDisk SecureAccess?